# DateUtils.formatElapsedTime unexpected behavior

Tags: android, datetime, date-format

Can anybody explain for me why DateUtils.formatElapsedTime have a different behavior on a different platforms? For example:

```
DateUtils.formatElapsedTime(75); //return "01:15" on nexus 4 (api lvl 22)
```

but

```
DateUtils.formatElapsedTime(75); //return " 01: 15" on HTC Desire 526G (api lvl 19)
```

and

```
DateUtils.formatElapsedTime(75); //return  "1:15" on zte leo M1 (api lvl 17)
```

to be more specific this method used inside [Chronometer](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Chronometer.html) class. How can i fix it?

Comment: You cannot fix it because different versions of Android implementations cause this behaviour. Otherwise if you are willing to distribute an app based on an external library with well defined behaviour then that would be a fix. For example using Time4A: `String s = Duration.formatter(ClockUnit.class, "#hh:mm").format(Duration.of(75, ClockUnit.MINUTES).with(Duration.STD_CLOCK_PERIOD));`Or in Joda-Time, you could use a `PeriodFormatter` (builder-based approach).